# How to detect ENTER KEY from a barcode scan in ASPX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, keypress

I have a textbox in WebForm, and user puts focus on that textbox and scan a barcode. The value scanned from the barcode gets put into the textbox. There is an ENTER KEY at the end of that value scanned. I would like to detect the ENTER KEY, but I dont know how to do it.

here is the code that popups message when a keypress occurs.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtProductCode").on("keypress", function () {
            alert("asdasd");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I found a tutorial to check the entered value like  below

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) ....
```

but I dont have the "e" object.... So how can I check the KeyCode on KeyPress

Comment: You could use the https://api.jquery.com/change/ then gets the value from the textbox, checks for an enter and continues there

Comment: Just to warn you not all barcode scanners send enters at the end. I wrote my app to expect barcodes of a specific format string and on string compatibility expect it to be the right barcode - so you can still manually type them if you wish, as some barcode scanners seem to paste, some send character by character, others press enter at the end, others dont

Comment: @BugFinder , thanks for the warning. I have already tested the barcodes and I am lucky

Comment: however, a new barcode reader may not - so in someways its a good idea to prepare for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `e` is the short var reference for `event object` which will be passed to event handlers.

The event object essentially has lot of interesting methods and properties that can be used in the event handlers, like the `keyup()` function.

```
$("#txtProductCode").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("asdasd");
    }
});
```

In your case, your are just missing the parameter.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtProductCode").on("keypress", function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("asdasd");
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can find more information in the `.on` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: any particular reason to use .keyup() rather than .keydown()?

Comment: @Ortund In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Late but may be helpful for someone else. This is controllable in some scanners like `Honeywell`. You just need to take a print [and follow the steps](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-remove-the-Enter-after-each-scan)